# Listing files in __dirname

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I'm learning ClojureScript and I'm trying to list files in `__dirname`, I can't get that to work, I suppose the problem is in how I get `__dirname` itself.

I have it working for a defined folder

```
(ns namespace
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as node]))

(def fs (node/require "fs"))

(.readdirSync fs "/home/me")
```

But when I do

```
(ns namespace
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as node]))

(def fs (node/require "fs"))

(.readdirSync fs node/__dirname)
```

I don't get anything, when I `cider-eval-last-sexp`. `node/__dirname` evaluates to `nil`, and I have this in the compiler output

> WARNING: Use of undeclared Var cljs.nodejs/__dirname

So, two questions:

1. I know that the final compiled script gets put in target/ so I should consider that the base folder, how do I specify this in my code?
2. I am using Spacemacs, I noticed errors go in *cider-repl CLJS my-project* buffer, how can I get them printed in the source buffer?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodejs/__dirname` is not defined. It has never been. There are only three defininitions in [that namespace](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/nodejs.cljs).

`__dirname` is a local variable to each node module. So if you want to access that variable, you have to do this:

```
(prn (.readdirSync fs (js* "__dirname")))
```

Comment: Yes that was my guess about `nodejs/__dirname`, thanks anyway. If anyone else is wondering about it, `prn` prints adding a new line, I've just looked it up.